# Receiving Invalid Column names in Unpivot Query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

When I try to run the following query in query analyzer I get the message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'TotalHours'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'ClientServiceHours'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'ClientPRDHours'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'OtherReportableTime'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'WeekendHours'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'FlightsPerWeek'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'Utilization'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'CEDHours'.

Here is the code I am running:

```
SELECT 
    THID AS 'ThresholdID', ThresholdID,
    TotalHours, ClientServiceHours, ClientPRDHours,
    OtherReportableTime, WeekendHours, FlightsPerWeek,
    HotelNightsPerWeek, Utilization, CEDHours,
    b.THX AS 'Threshold', ThresholdID AS 'ThresholdValue'
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         THID,
         TotalHours, ClientServiceHours, ClientPRDHours,
         OtherReportableTime, WeekendHours, FlightsPerWeek,
         HotelNightsPerWeek, Utilization, CEDHours
     FROM 
         [dbo].[MyTable]) AS a
UNPIVOT
(
     ThresholdID FOR THX IN (
        TotalHours, ClientServiceHours, ClientPRDHours,
        OtherReportableTime, WeekendHours, FlightsPerWeek,
        Utilization, CEDHours)
) AS b
ORDER BY THID
```

Here is the table layout I am working with along with a small amount of the data in the current table:

```
THRESHOLDID THID    TOTALHOURS  CLIENTSERVICEHOURS  CLIENTPRDHOURS  OTHERREPORTABLETIME WEEKENDHOURS    FLIGHTSPERWEEK  HOTELNIGHTSPERWEEK  UTILIZATION CEDHOURS
0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
1   1   55.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.10    5.00    5.00    90.00   0.00
2   2   55.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.10    5.00    5.00    90.00   0.00
3   3   55.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.10    5.00    5.00    90.00   0.00
4   4   55.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.10    5.00    5.00    90.00   0.00
5   5   55.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.10    5.00    5.00    80.00   0.00
6   6   55.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.10    5.00    5.00    70.00   0.00
7   7   55.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.10    5.00    5.00    70.00   0.00
8   8   41.67   39.93   7.90    0.00    0.31    1.24    3.00    1.00    0.00
9   9   45.49   39.70   12.51   0.00    0.88    1.10    3.00    0.99    0.00
```

As you can see the column names are correct. I am wondering if anyone has any idea why I am receiving the error message that the column names are invalid. I am running this on a SQL Server 2014 database.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
nbw

Comment: Can you post the DDL of MyTable? Also, is this a complete error list or is there another error like `The type of column "XXX" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the expected result?

Your code will work only with this syntax:

```
select  THID as 'ThresholdID',
        ThresholdID TotalHours,
b.THX AS 'Threshold', ThresholdID AS 'ThresholdValue'
from    (
            select  
                    TotalHours,
                    ClientServiceHours,
                    ClientPRDHours,
                    OtherReportableTime,
                    WeekendHours,
                    FlightsPerWeek,
                    HotelNightsPerWeek,
                    Utilization,
                    CEDHours,
                    THID
            from    [dbo].[MyTable]
        ) as a
UNPIVOT(ThresholdID for THX in(
    TotalHours,
    ClientServiceHours,
    ClientPRDHours,
    OtherReportableTime,
    WeekendHours,
    FlightsPerWeek,
    Utilization,
    CEDHours
)
) as b
order by    THID
```